# Enable TextWatcher when EditText is disabled

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

in my app I have to disabled `EditText`  and changing text in `EditText` programatically, problem is I want `EditText` to listen for TextWatcher which I added on `EditText`.

But `EditText` is not listening watcher.

So can anyone please help to enable `EditText` listen for `TextWatcher` while it is disabled and text is populated to `EditText` programatically not through `KeyBoard`.

I tried the below code

```
txtShift.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (s.length()>0) {
                keyPadOnOff(false);
            }else {
                keyPadOnOff(true);

            }       
        }
    });
```

thanks

Comment: If text is populated to EditText programatically then why did you need TextWatcher? Can't you trigger event at the time of setting text to EditText?

Comment: What you have tried for that?

Comment: @DhavalPatel, yes I have this option only to trigger action while populating text, if it is not possible through watcher

Comment: @Amy I updated my question

Comment: @androicode: have you tried it as `et.setFocusable(false);et.setClickable(false);` ?

Comment: @androicode I think you only have the DhavalPatel's suggestion to do this.

Comment: yes i set focusable and clickable as false

Answer (score 0):

Check the followings

1. Are you import this line ?- import android.text.TextWatcher;
2. Are you Initialize the EditText properly?
3. Set a Log.v on method - afterTextChanged(Editable s) and check it first.

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

   Log.v(TAG,"AfterTextChanged worked");

   }
4. If the 3rd point correctly get Log values. 
   The error is in the method  keyPadOnOff(boolean)

5.Check the method keyPadOnOff(boolean).

Answer (score 0):

after so much digging at Google I found we are unable to make `EditText` listen for watcher if it made

```
et.setFocusable(false);
et.setClickable(false);
```

So what I did, I trigger the event when I am populating text in `EditText` from my code.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable TextWatcher with this line:

```
txtShift.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

you can start with:

```
txtShift.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length()>0) {
                keyPadOnOff(false);
            }else {
                keyPadOnOff(true);
            }

        }
    };
```